# How to Stop File From Opening Using Ebpf?

Tags: python, linux, file, filesystems, ebpf

I want to use EBPF and place a probe on the open syscall, so when a user wants to open a certain file I will check its name and if it is the targeted name I will stop it from opening. The only thing is I do not know how to actually achieve this goal.

In addition, I would appreciate if you could specify if a certain solution works with uprobe or root probe.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What happens if the user makes a symlink to the file and tries to open that?  Or a hard link?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR.** There's currently no way to do this using BPF.

---

There is currently **no option in the Linux kernel to enforce policies on syscalls using eBPF.** This may change with the introduction of eBPF-based LSMs (Linux Security Modules) though (see [*Kernel Runtime Security Instrumentation*](https://lwn.net/Articles/798918/), [*KRSI — the other BPF security module*](https://lwn.net/Articles/808048/), and [*KRSI and proprietary BPF programs*](https://lwn.net/Articles/809841/)).

You can however **enforce policies on syscalls with seccomp-bpf**, but it uses cBPF, the old BPF bytecode, instead of eBPF. It is nevertheless **not possible to inspect syscall arguments passed by pointers with seccomp-bpf**, for [security reasons](https://lwn.net/Articles/799557/); so you wouldn't be able to check the name of the file being opened.

Comment: Do you know another way to stop a user when he is opening a file?

Comment: I'd check AppArmor and SELinux out (they are other LSMs).

Comment: Technically, using seccomp-bpf, one can conditionally trigger SIGSYS that would be synchronously sent to the precise thread that have called a suspicious syscall. Then, userspace SIGSYS handler can somehow process args from ucontext passed to the handler and conditionally pass them through or so. Personally me, I use a trick with passing some known marker int as a highest (currently, 6th) syscall arg as a pass-through sign. This does not work with mmap and other 6-args syscalls, though. This expects that programs would not specifically hinder preloading or so.

Comment: Yes, there are several options to defer decision making to userspace, including `SECCOMP_RET_USER_NOTIF` and `SECCOMP_RET_TRACE`. I didn't include those in the answer because @Liroshka was specifically asking for a BPF-based solution. I'd argue that, for their use case, SELinux/Apparmor are easier solutions anyway :-)